# Show that $|vol_{2\times1}(u_1,u_2)|=1$ if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the orthonormal basis of $R^{2\times1}$

Tags: matrices

My try:

If $(u_1,u_2)$ is the orthonormal base, it means that $\begin{bmatrix} u_1  &u_2\\  \end{bmatrix}$ is invertible. This also means that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly independent.

so $\begin{bmatrix} u_1  &u_2\\  \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix} e_1  &e_2\\  \end{bmatrix}$

and $|vol_{2\times1}(u_1,u_2)|=|vol_{2\times1}(e_1,e_2)|=1$

The last part doesn't seem right and I'm 100% sure that this is not the right way to do this. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: what is your definition of volume?

Comment: @Riquelme If $A=\begin{bmatrix} u_1  &u_2\\  \end{bmatrix}$ then $det A= vol_{2\times1}(u_1,u_2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A real square matrix is orthogonal iff its columns form an orthonormal basis, which holds iff its rows form an orthonormal basis. Convince yourself that an orthogonal matrix $Q$ then must satisfy $QQ'=\mathbb{I}$, and use properties of determinants to show $\det(Q)=\pm 1.$

Comment: Thank you, I got it! It was simpler than I thought.